# Dictionary TryGetValue without using value returned

Tags: c#, .net, performance, dictionary

I'm implementing a simple `Dictionary<String, Int>` that keeps track of picture files I download, and also the renaming of the files.

`String` - original filename

`Int`    - new filename

I read up on `TryGetValue` vs `ContainsKey` and came across this:

> `TryGetValue` approach is faster than `ContainsKey` approach but only when
>   you want to check the key in collection and also want to get the value
>   associated with it. If you only want to check the key is present or
>   not use `ContainsKey` only.

from [here](http://pranayamr.blogspot.sg/2011/06/dictionary-object-containskey-vs.html)

As such, I was wondering what were other people's views on the following:

Should I use `TryGetValue` even if I do not plan to use the returned `value`, assuming the Dictonary size would grow to 1000 entries, and I do duplicate checks everytime I download ie. frequently?

Comment: The quote says that `d.TryGetValue(key, out value)` is faster than `value = d.ContainsKey(key) ? d[key] : null`, not that it is always faster than ContainsKey.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, follow the documentation. If you don't want the value then use `ContainsKey` because there's no code to go and actually grab the value out of memory.

Now, in practice, it probably doesn't matter because you're micro-optimizing on a `Dictionary` that's probably very small in the grand scheme of things. So, in practice, do what is best for you and the readability of your code.

And just to help you get a good idea, `would grow to 1000 entries` is **really small** so it really isn't going to matter in practice.

Comment: pretty open and shut case

Answer (score 4):

> If you only want to check the key is present or not use ContainsKey only.

I think you answered the question for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see the implementation of both under Reflector

```
public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
{
    int index = this.FindEntry(key);
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        value = this.entries[index].value;
        return true;
    }
    value = default(TValue);
    return false;
}

public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
{
    return (this.FindEntry(key) >= 0);
}
```

this is how both the methods are implemented.

Now you can decide yourself which method is best.

Answer (score 1):

I think that performance gains (if any) aren't worth the cost of obfuscating your code with this optimization.

Balance the scale your targeting with code maintainability. E.g.:

~10K concurrent calls average vs. < 5 developer team size GO FOR IT! 
~500 concurrent call average vs. > 50 developer team size DON'T DO IT!